# how to integrate soap xml api with web service in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am new to PHP. I have a busBooking soap api and i want to integrate it in my php application.

I have the following details

Login URL : http://api.tektravels.com/BusBookingAPI/Service.asmx

and login name and password

and i have the six sampleXML set like the below:

BusBookRequest,
BusBookResponse,
BusSearchRequest,
BusSearchResponse,
BusSeatDetailRequest,
BusSeatDetailResponse

the following is BusBookRequest XML
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <WSBookRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    <ProductTypeId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">0</ProductTypeId>    <ProductId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">0</ProductId>    <BookingMode xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">Auto</BookingMode>    <ProductType xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">Bus</ProductType>    <BusId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">0</BusId>    <SourceId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">1492</SourceId>    <DestinationId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">1135</DestinationId>    <SourceName xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">Delhi</SourceName>    <DestinationName xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">Manali</DestinationName>    <DateOfJourney xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">2014-09-26T00:00:00</DateOfJourney>    <BusSource xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">RedBus</BusSource>    <IsDomestic xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">true</IsDomestic>    <RouteId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">201653313640000758</RouteId>    <BusType xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">Volvo A/C Seater Semi Sleeper (2+2)</BusType>    <TravelName xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">Royal Travels</TravelName>    <NoOfSeats xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">1</NoOfSeats>    <DepartureTime xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">2014-09-26T17:00:00</DepartureTime>    <ArrivalTime xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">2014-09-27T07:00:00</ArrivalTime>    <TotalFare xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">1450.00</TotalFare>    <BoardingPointdetails xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">      <CityPointId>21533</CityPointId>      <BusId>0</BusId>      <CityPointName>Paharganj</CityPointName>      <CityPointLocation>Paharganj</CityPointLocation>      <CityPointLandmark>Opp Paharganj Police Station</CityPointLandmark>      <CityPointAddress>Shop No. BG 16,Ground Floor,RG City Centre,Opp. Paharganj Police Station,Delhi</CityPointAddress>      <CityPointContactNumber>011-43074720/9899199491/9953733177/9873787138</CityPointContactNumber>      <CityPointTime>2014-09-26T17:00:00</CityPointTime>    </BoardingPointdetails>    <CancelPolicy xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">      <WSCancellationPolicies>        <BusId>0</BusId>        <TimeBeforeDept>0$15</TimeBeforeDept>        <CancellationChargeType>Percentage</CancellationChargeType>        <CancellationCharge>100</CancellationCharge>      </WSCancellationPolicies>      <WSCancellationPolicies>        <BusId>0</BusId>        <TimeBeforeDept>15$-1</TimeBeforeDept>        <CancellationChargeType>Percentage</CancellationChargeType>        <CancellationCharge>10</CancellationCharge>      </WSCancellationPolicies>    </CancelPolicy>    <PaxDetail xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">      <BusId>0</BusId>      <PaxId>0</PaxId>      <Title>Mr.</Title>      <LastName>kjhj</LastName>      <FirstName>hkhjk</FirstName>      <Age>21</Age>      <PhoneNo>9876543211</PhoneNo>      <EMail>sonam@travelboutiqueonline.com</EMail>      <Gender>male</Gender>    </PaxDetail>    <SeatsDetail xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">      <WSBusSeatDetail>        <SeatId>0</SeatId>        <BusId>0</BusId>        <SeatName>27</SeatName>        <SeatType>sleeper</SeatType>        <RowNo>003</RowNo>        <ColumnNo>006</ColumnNo>        <SeatStatus>1</SeatStatus>        <SeatFare>725.00</SeatFare>        <priceId>0</priceId>        <Width>1</Width>        <Height>1</Height>        <IsLadies>false</IsLadies>        <IsUpper>false</IsUpper>        <Price>          <TdsCommission>3.62</TdsCommission>          <PriceId>0</PriceId>          <PublishedFare>725.00</PublishedFare>          <AgentCommission>36.25</AgentCommission>          <SeviceTax>0.00</SeviceTax>          <Tax>0</Tax>          <Currency />          <RateOfExchange>1.0</RateOfExchange>          <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>          <Discount>0</Discount>          <TdsRate>0</TdsRate>        </Price>      </WSBusSeatDetail>      <WSBusSeatDetail>        <SeatId>0</SeatId>        <BusId>0</BusId>        <SeatName>28</SeatName>        <SeatType>sleeper</SeatType>        <RowNo>004</RowNo>        <ColumnNo>006</ColumnNo>        <SeatStatus>1</SeatStatus>        <SeatFare>725.00</SeatFare>        <priceId>0</priceId>        <Width>1</Width>        <Height>1</Height>        <IsLadies>false</IsLadies>        <IsUpper>false</IsUpper>        <Price>          <TdsCommission>3.62</TdsCommission>          <PriceId>0</PriceId>          <PublishedFare>725.00</PublishedFare>          <AgentCommission>36.25</AgentCommission>          <SeviceTax>0.00</SeviceTax>          <Tax>0</Tax>          <Currency />          <RateOfExchange>1.0</RateOfExchange>          <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>          <Discount>0</Discount>          <TdsRate>0</TdsRate>        </Price>      </WSBusSeatDetail>    </SeatsDetail>    <Currency xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">INR</Currency>    <SessionId xmlns="http://192.168.0.131/TT/BusBookingAPI">57f27951-0018-411b-b0a1-d23cdb366c04</SessionId>  </WSBookRequest>`

please help me how to integrate it with this details and how to access the response with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start reading [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).

Start with:

```php
$wsdl = 'http://api.tektravels.com/BusBookingAPI/Service.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

Comment: its showing error Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found ?

Comment: check in your php.ini file whether it is enabled or not